# Join more than one node in a new node

Tags: node-red

I wish to create a custom node in Node-red by joining together multiple built-in nodes (or custom ones, created by me). Is this possible?

I could not find, natively, this functionality and also couldn't find any contribs.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at sub flows?

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for :)